# Dynamically added hidden input to Django form results in KeyError

Tags: django

In my code I have jQuery method with which I am adding value dynamically to my form on submit. The code looks like this:

form_page.html

```
<form id="objectForm" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% include 'manage/form-template.html'%}
    <button id="submitBtn">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitBtn").click(function(){
        $("#objectForm").submit(function(){
          $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden")
          .attr("name", "dates")
          .attr("value", "something")
          .appendTo("#objectForm");
          return true;
         }); // Submit the form
    });
  });
</script>
```

views.py

```
class ObjectUpdateView(UpdateView):

    template_name = 'manage/object_form.html'
    form_class = ObjectEditForm
    def get_success_url(self):
        #...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        clean = form.cleaned_data['dates']
        print('Dates: ', clean)
        return super(ObjectUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class ObjectEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
     model = Object
     fields = ['TestField']
```

This code is resulting in KeyError on the `clean = form.cleaned_data['dates']` line. Debugging POST values in Chrome I can see that value itself is set properly. For some reason Django is not registering this.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do, to access this value in Python?

**EDIT**

Based on the discussion in the comments I wanted to update a bit what I'm looking for.

I am aware that `ObjectEditForm` has only single field. The reason for that is I only have this one field in my `Object` model. Another field `dates`, which I am trying to add, I am trying to add is going to be used in view.On my html website I am also using JS calendar, from which I am collecting dates on submit method and putting those into this extra field.

Comment: But your `ObjectEditForm` contains only one field `TestField`? So that means the `Form` will ignore the remaining content, since it is possible *another* form is interested in that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, I am aware that my form has only one field defined in class. But I'm not sure how other way I can dynamically add data from javascript to form. Adding hidden, dynamic field seemed the most reasonable.

Comment: the question is, do you need the form. You can access data in `self.request.POST['dates']`. A form is meant to *validate* a model, or something with (more or less) a fixed structure.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, I do need. Because form is used to update one set of fields and then I am also adding extra value from Javascript function to my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Not the prettiest one, but does the work. There were actually two things to do:
1. modify forms.py

```
class ObjectEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
 dates = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
 class Meta:
     model = Object
     fields = ['TestField']
```

2. Modify form fields printing. Since I have a `forloop` over all fields I had to add if condition to not display anything related to `dates` field.

Now, everything seems to be working. If someone has cleaner idea I'd appreciate that.